# Redirect echo and python output into a file

Tags: bash

How can I redirect the output of this command into a file:

```
for i in seq_chr*; do echo -n -e "$i \t"; ./script.py $i ; done
```

The output to the screen is as follows:

```
seq_chr1    0.005   14.145045   871199
seq_chr10   0.004   17.729745   105156
```

But I can't figure out how to redirect both the outcome of echo and my python script to a file. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the redirection operator `>` after the `for` loop :

```
for .... >/where/to/save
```

so in your case :

```
for i in seq_chr*; do echo -n -e "$i \t"; ./script.py $i ; done >/where/to/save
```